# How can I find $E[ Z \mid Z > 0]$ for $Z \sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I don’t know the definition of $E[Z \mid Z > 0]$. I looked it up but only multi variable answers showed up.

What I tried to do is to use the definition of $E[Z]$ changing the integration limits from $0$ to infinity and multiplying the integral by $1/2$. However, I am not sure if that is the way to do it.

Comment: Following George's suggestion on Baye's rule, you can observe: For $z>0$ we have:
$$P[Z \leq z|Z>0] = \frac{P[\{Z\leq z\} \cap \{Z>0\}]}{P[Z>0]} = \frac{P[0<Z\leq z]}{P[Z>0]}$$
You can write the above in terms of the CDF $F_Z(z)$ if you like, and you can take a derivative with respect to $z$ to obtain the conditional PDF $f_{Z|Z>0}(z)$.

Comment: @Michael Is finding the probability the same as finding the expected vale?

Comment: Finding the conditional PDF is not the same as finding the conditional expectation. But it is a step in that direction:  Can you give an expression for $E[Z|Z>0]$ in terms of $f_{Z|Z>0}(z)$ ?

Comment: @Michael I haven’t learned the conditional PDF. Is there an other way to do it?

Comment: In that case, how would you define $E[Z|Z>0]$?

Comment: @Michael I understand now. It is the integral of z times its density probability function over the interval 0 to infinity divided by 1/2

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388737/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct but you also divide by the probability of $Z>0$ i.e. bayes rule

Comment: I wonder if Lollipop's "multiplying by $1/2$" was intended to be "dividing by $1/2$", which would then be your suggestion.