# question about the notation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable. We need to compute the integral 
$$E(X~|X>0).$$
In the book, they give the answer ${1\over \sqrt{2\pi}}$. Then I am confused with this conditional expectation notation.
Since from my understanding, it should be 
$$\int_0^\infty 2\cdot {x\over \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-{x^2\over 2}}\, dx$$
which gives the answer $\sqrt{{2\over\pi}}$. I add a factor "2" here. Can anyone tell me this conditon expectation $E(X|X>0)$ notation meaning? Since it is not standard, we usually conditioning on a $\sigma$-algebra, rather than a set.

Comment: You are right as far as I can tell.

Comment: In my experience, when one sees $E(A\mid B),$ usually $B$ is a set. It seems unusual to me to put an entire sigma algebra in that place in the formula. But that doesn't rule out the possibility that your book uses the notation $E(A\mid B)$ in a non-standard way when $B$ is a set. It might be instructive to see whether that use of the notation occurs in any other examples or exercises and what results are given for those occurrences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [the wikipedia page for conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event), we should have
$$E(X|A) = \frac{E(X\mathbf{1}_A)}{P(A)}$$

In particular, $E(X|X>0) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ when $X$ is a standard normal.

---

Related, I believe I have seen the notation $E(X;A) := E(X\mathbf{1}_A),$ which would give an answer of $E(X;X>0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$